# php ie9 automatic downloads

Tags: php, automation, download, internet-explorer-9

Hi guys I'm trying to get an automatic download box to appear when people go a page.
I've got this working on all the browsers and now ie9 has come along and although it downloads at the end it says "This download was interrupted"

this is what I'm using code wise

```
// set headers
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT\n");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$download[file]\";\n\n");
    header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
    header("Content-Type: ".$mtype);
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".(string)$size.";\n");


    //get a chunk of the file
    $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024); // how many bytes per chunk
    $buffer = '';

     //downloads file
    $handle = fopen($download_file, 'rb');
    if ($handle === false) {
    }
    //write to the browser for download
    while (!feof($handle)) {
     $buffer = fread($handle, $chunksize);
     echo $buffer;
     ob_flush();
     flush();
     if ($retbytes) {
       $cnt += strlen($buffer);
     }
    }
    exit;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have two `Content-Description: File Transfer` headers being sent?

Comment: you got 2 Content-Description:'s and no need for the `\n's` on the headers

Comment: the 2 Content-Description: File Transfer was it!, I don't know how to give you props - I clicked the arrow next to your comment but anyway cheers that's had us stumped for most of the morning!

Comment: Thanks again for your comments, I've removed some of the headers and cleaned up the code I did try readfile but these files are quite big and that doesn't seem to want to work. The download is better but I still get the interupted message. In fact even on small files there are problems - I'm wondering if this is a problem with my internet connection.
If there are any other ideas it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the somewhat complicated file output you're doing, I'd just use [readfile](http://us.php.net/readfile) instead:

```
// set headers
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT\n");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$download[file]\";\n\n");
header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
header("Content-Type: ".$mtype);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".(string)$size.";\n");

readfile($download_file);
exit;
```

See if that works.

Comment: +1...and lose the header() statements which aren't actualy doing anything (i.e. at least half)